# How to consume direct link to identity provider with azure B2C?

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c, maui

I would like to consume third party identity provider in my application.
B2C provide a MSAL WebView authentication with pre-generated or custom page layout
(with username, password, and button for social providers).
like below

[image]

But I would like to create my own native button, that will open directly the web view on the specific identity provider.
Does Microsoft provide such flow without using the pre-generated or custom page layout,
but redirect instantly to the Identity provider?

If Microsoft does not, where can I suggest new feature, enhancement and vote for them?

Let me know,
Regards :)

Comment: Not possible as per my understanding. Ideally, you should use Custom Flows in AD B2C or customize the UI. Else create a native UI and handle them yourselves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use domain_hint parameter. If you open your policy with &domain_hint=facebook.com it will go directly to the selected identity provider.

Doc ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/direct-signin?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#redirect-sign-in-to-a-social-provider

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-spa-app-options#preselect-an-identity-provider

Comment: Bro you save my day <3